# How to make a leaderboard

Tags: php, arrays

Hey everyone I just made this code in php, where it prints out the list of all students and their score from higher to lower and after that shows the top 3 depending on the score.

```
<?php

$Turma = array(

array("name" => "Diogo", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("name" => "Joao","score" => "500", "time" => "3" ),
array("name" => "Miguel", "score" => "125", "score" => "8" ),
array("name" => "Daniela", "score" => "105", "time" => "7" ),
array("name" => "Joana", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("name" => "Diogo", "score" => "275", "time" => "4" ),
array("name" => "Francisco", "score" => "300", "time" => "9" ),
array("name" => "Ines", "score" => "650", "time" => "2" ),
array("name" => "Dionisio", "score" => "101", "score" => "10" ),
array("name" => "Ricardo", "score" => "200", "score" => "8" ),
array("name" => "Fabio", "score" => "201", "score" => "11" ),
array("name" => "Tiago","score" => "50", "score" => "13" ),
array("name" => "Carolina", "score" => "150", "time" => "5" ), 
array("name" => "Rui", "score" => "130", "time" => "3" ),
array("name" => "Luisa", "score" => "1000", "time" => "1" ),

);


 usort($Turma, function($a,$b){
    return $b["score"] - $a["score"];


});

 foreach($Turma as $key => $value) {
    
    $position = $key + 1;
    
    echo "{$position}: {$value['nome']} : {$value['score']} <br>";

}






echo "<br>";
echo "WINNERS!! <br> ";

foreach($Turma as $key => $value) {
    
    $position = $key + 1;

    if ($position < 4) {
        echo "{$position}: {$value['nome']} : {$value['score']} <br>";
    }

    
}
```

Now i must see if in the main list there are any draws in terms of score and if its true then the fastest wins, if there is a draw in terms of score and time we order by their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close; you just need to alter your callback in `usort` to take into account the `time` (and `name`) fields when the `score` (and `time`) fields are equal:

```
usort($Turma, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['score'] != $b['score']) return $b['score'] - $a['score'];
    if ($a['time'] != $b['time']) return $a['time'] - $b['time'];
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});

echo "<br>";
echo "WINNERS!! <br> ";
foreach ($Turma as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 3) break;
    $position = $key + 1;
    echo "{$position}: {$value['name']} : {$value['score']} <br>";
}
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
<br>WINNERS!! <br> 1: Luisa : 1000 <br>2: Ines : 650 <br>3: Joao : 500 <br>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mjPNY)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a clause to the usort function which compares the time if the difference in score is 0.

```
function($a, $b){
    $diff = doubleval($b["score"]) - doubleval($a["score"]);
    if($diff != 0) return $diff;
    return doubleval($b["time"]) - doubleval($a["time"]);
}
```

---

By the way, some of your array entries seem to have a duplicate score key rather than a score and a time key.

```
array("name" => "Miguel", "score" => "125", "score" => "8" ),
```

Comment: thank you for your awnser, do I put that function below the usort part?

Comment: Yes this would replace your inline usort function.